# TypeConverter IsValid not fireing

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

I want to implement input validation on a `PropertyGrid`. I've figured out that I need a `TypeConverter` and throw an Exception in the `ConvertFrom` method. This works just fine except that it shows a standard "message box". I wish to show my own. According to MSDN the exception is catched in the `IsValid` method. So I've tried to override it an do my thing there but it doesn't even fire.

My Code:

```
public class ParameterNameConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        Debug.Print("ConvertFrom");
        if (Convert.ToString(value).Contains(" "))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Invalid input");
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for `IsValid()` from the [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/TypeConverter.cs,fecc22cbe2f40c25). You can see that `IsValid()` calls `ConvertFrom()` itself and try catches it. So you would need to perform a similar operation calling your own `ConvertFrom()` method from your own `IsValid()` method, and then handle the exception. If you simply don't override `IsValid()` then the base method `IsValid()` would silently eat your `exception` and return the standard `false` response.

Although it sounds to me like your `IsValid()` method is never being called at all if you're not seeing your own message box pop up from your example code? But that's a different question :P

Comment: Well thank you, It somehow helped me. It seems like the way to go is to call `IsValid()` myself but I cant figure out where... `ConferFrom` would be a good place since i have the new value there but what do I do if `IsValid` returns false... If I throw an exception I end up having 2 message boxes...